# What is /dev/ttyAMA0

Tags: serial

complete newbie here. Can someone please tell me what /dev/ttyAMA0.
I read that it is the TxRx pins. But what is it? is it used to refer to the pins or their address?
is it explicitly the Rx or the tx pin?

Comment: related: [What is the difference between ttys0, ttyUSB0 and ttyAMA0 in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307390/what-is-the-difference-between-ttys0-ttyusb0-and-ttyama0-in-linux).

Answer (score 17):

@Milliways had the best answer in my opinion. His answer can be found here: [Link given here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3/45571#45571)

ttyAMA0 can be the Tx, Rx pins for the Raspberry. But for the Raspberry Pi 3b it was used for the Bluetooth. Because of this, pins 8 & 10 were using the miniUART which is labeled ttyS0 (unless you disable the Bluetooth which has instructions in that link in the beginning of this post)

So to answer you question, it can refer to pins 8 and 10 if you disable the Bluetooth. It is both the RX and TX pins as it refers to the device it self, which contains both pins.

I hope this and the answer by Milliways helps you out.

Comment: this was hugely helpful. @Milliways gives a comprehensive answer and your answer made sense to what he was talking about. Thanks a lot. I am a complete novice to Rpi and everybit is very intimidating. However I am trying my best to get a good grasp of it. I was wondering if you could send me your mail Id, if you dont mind me contacting you directly for any future doubts. :)

Comment: No problem. Glad I could be of some assistance. Be sure to click the answer button so when other people are searching for similar questions, they can see that this question was answered. It'll make their searches easire.